# Improve this query that uses 3 joins in Oracle, maybe using "partition over"?

Tags: oracle, query-optimization

I have a query which is not performing as I want it to perform. I use it on almost all pages to display in the footer a list of 4 random tutors and some of their associated data (their name, their avatar, and how many courses they offer).

How can I improve this query's execution speed in Oracle? I was looking at partitions and using partition over and other stuff. I have a mySQL background and I'm probably not using Oracle at its full power.

I have the following table structure:

```
tutor_profiles:
    id
    user_id (FK users)

 users:
     id
     username
     avatar_id (FK files)

 courses:
     id
     tutor_id (FK tutor_profiles)
     description
     ...

  files
      id
      file_uri
```

`

And I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT inner_query.*, rownum rnum 
    FROM (
        SELECT tutor_profiles.id AS "tutor_id"
            , tutor_profiles.full_name AS "full_name"
            , files.file_uri as "file_uri"
            , files.id AS file_id
            , tutor_profiles.user_id
            , count(distinct courses.id) AS "course_count" 
        FROM tutor_profiles 
            LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = tutor_profiles.user_id 
            LEFT JOIN files ON files.id = users.avatar_id 
            LEFT JOIN courses ON tutor_profiles.id = courses.tutor_id 
        GROUP BY tutor_profiles.id, tutor_profiles.full_name, tutor_profiles.user_id, files.file_uri, files.id 
        ORDER BY dbms_random.VALUE
    ) inner_query 
    WHERE rownum <= 4)
```

Comment: What is the query suppose to do?

Comment: the query is supposed to get 4 random tutors from the database with how many courses they have, their profile avatar

Answer (score 2):

for starters - how are your indexes?

you should have indexes on

```
users.id
files.id
tutor_profiles.user_id
tutor_profiles.id
courses.tutor_id
users.avatar_id
```

after that (actually maybe before that), what is the explain plan showing?

how many records approximately in the tables?

Comment: 500 records, I do not have indexes, I am using PHP with Oracle, and will use memcache anyway to cache the results

Comment: You would be much better off generating 4 random tutors (who may have other requirements than being "a tutor"), and then generating the data that are needed from them.

Comment: Are you using Oracle's SQL*Developer product?  It has a very nice EXPLAIN PLAN button in the worksheet editor.

Answer (score 2):

As Andy Finkenstadt suggested you may be better off selecting 4 random tutors and then selecting 4 random values from your remaining result set. Although this means that you're ordering by `dbms_random.value` twice - which does look worse - it does mean that the datasets you're doing this ordering on are much smaller.

You should also ensure that there are indexes as per [Randy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9705636/458741).

Pet peeve, the `"` to produce cased column names, unless you have a *very* good reason for this it is *never* worth the extra hassle it causes. You'll always have to reference them with the inverted commas for a start.

If you want to try using analytic functions, which may speed things up you should add a `distinct` in the select with the `count` and replace `count(distinct c.id)` with `count(distinct c.id) over ()`. This means that you're counting a `distinct` `id` for all rows. If you added a `partition by` clause you'd do this count for whatever is in the partition. You should also completely remove the `group by`.

I've also removed an additional sub-select, which wasn't required.

```
select *
  from ( select tp.id as tutor_id
              , tp.full_name as full_name
              , f.file_uri as file_uri
              , f.id AS file_id
              , tp.user_id
              , count(distinct c.id) as course_count 
           from ( select *
                    from ( select id 
                                , full_name
                                , user_id
                             from tutor_profiles
                            order by dbms_random.value )
                   where rownum <= 4 ) tp
           left outer join users u
             on u.id = tp.user_id 
           left outer join files f
             on f.id = u.avatar_id 
           left outer join courses c
             on tp.id = c.tutor_id 
          group by tp.id, tp.full_name, tp.user_id, f.file_uri, f.id
          order by dbms_random.value )
 where rownum <= 4
```

Comment: You may also improve performance by using a random sample from the first table.  For example: `from tutor_profiles sample(5)`.  Picking the right sample percent can be tricky.  You want a small percent to retrieve as little data as possible, but you need a number large enough to ensure that you will always get at least 4 rows.  But on the other hand, if the number of rows is very small it may be faster to do a full table scan instead of reading a few blocks one-at-a-time.

Comment: aaa...this query runs even worse than my first query

Comment: @Mythriel, the 6th word is _may_ :-). Have you created the indexes the cache will only work after the first run won't it?

Comment: yes the cache will work only after first run, I created the index on tutor_profiles.full_name